# bootstrap navbar even spacing

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I do not know how to set even spacing in my navbar:

there is a bigger gap between Articles and User Profil than User Profil and Admin.

There is a bigger gap between Admin and DB than User Profil and Admin.

[image]

My code is:

```
<li class="blog-nav-item">
        <a class="blog-nav-item" href="#" class="blog-nav-item active" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Articles<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/articles/create">All</a></li>
            <li><a href="/articles/create">Create New</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>   

<a class="blog-nav-item" href="/accounts/profil/">User Profil</a></li>
<a class="blog-nav-item" href="/admin/">Admin</a></li>

<li class="blog-nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="blog-nav-item" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">DB<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="/articles/api/article/?format=json">DB: JSON</a></li>
        <li><a href="/articles/api/article/?format=xml">DB: XML</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because, by default, there is different margin spacing for a simple list element and a drop down menu.

Override the settings by:

```
.blog-nav-item > a{
    margin-right:10px;
}
.blog-nav-item > .dropdown-menu{
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

Adding these classes to the css will help

Comment: I am not sure where should I place it: in blog.css or in bootstrap.min.css ? I believe I should place it in blog.css and I have tried it but it does not change anything.

Comment: You'd need to include blog.css in the head of your file. Also it'd make sense to add text-align: center; to .blog-nav-item class.

Comment: ok, I have created a new css file: test.css in which I placed your code. I have included it in my index.html file as well. There is no change if I modify the 2nd pixel value. I can see a change if I modify 1st pixel value. Although, the change makes a gap between Articles & User Profil either wider or smaller and it depends on value (smaller for value -5px, wider for value +15px). I think it is not right way to change it.